# I tried to bring up the map server, but it doesn't seem to be coming up

Tags: rviz, slam, nav2

When I try to run the Nav2 stack

```
ros2 run nav2_map_server map_server --ros-args -p yaml_filename:=my_map_save.yaml -p 
use_sim_time:=true
```

The execution log of the above command

```
[INFO] [1703343999.250577364] [map_server]: 
map_server lifecycle node launched. 
Waiting on external lifecycle transitions to activate
See https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html for more information.
[INFO] [1703343999.255554676] [map_server]: Creating
```

The next time you try to run it

```
ros2 run nav2_util lifecycle_bringup map_server
```

I can see that my server is running. Even the pgm file seems to have loaded well.

```
\[INFO] [1703343999.250577364] [map_server]: 
map_server lifecycle node launched. 
Waiting on external lifecycle transitions to activate
See https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html for more information.
[INFO] [1703343999.255554676] [map_server]: Creating
[INFO] [1703344106.807486936] [map_server]: Configuring
[INFO] [map_io]: Loading yaml file: my_map_save.yaml
[DEBUG] [map_io]: resolution: 0.05
[DEBUG] [map_io]: origin[0]: -5.55
[DEBUG] [map_io]: origin[1]: -5.59
[DEBUG] [map_io]: origin[2]: 0
[DEBUG] [map_io]: free_thresh: 0.25
[DEBUG] [map_io]: occupied_thresh: 0.65
[DEBUG] [map_io]: mode: trinary
[DEBUG] [map_io]: negate: 0
[INFO] [map_io]: Loading image_file: ./my_map_save.pgm
[DEBUG] [map_io]: Read map ./my_map_save.pgm: 177 X 161 map @ 0.05 m/cell
[INFO] [1703344106.883651648] [map_server]: Activating
[INFO] [1703344106.884993461] [map_server]: Creating bond (map_server) to lifecycle manager.
```

The last time I run rviz2, it creates a different screen than the scene I thought.

I expected this stuation
[image]

But it was against my expectations
[image]

Should I start the Slam Toolbox node or rename the map server?

My ros2 version is humble

And I referred to this video

[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZaiA3hWaRzE&list=RDCMUCx9vSJTSZGFrErfPtut5GNQ&index=2)

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

On the bottom left of Rviz there is a "Add" button. You need to add a map and choose the map topic to display in Rviz.

Also, it might be just for me, but if no node subscribes to `/map` before you run `map_server` and `lifecycle_bringup`, the posted `/map` topic will disappear. So I would say start Rviz and add a map display before running the `map_server` and `lifecycle_bringup`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are dealing with Rviz settings. What param file are you loading with Rviz? It can specify the different views.